# Reuse one schema for multiple Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to search for this, but my results are always flooded with "multiple schemas per Kafka topic" entries. I'd like to know the other way round, if it may be problematic or if I could expect issues with reusing the same schema for different Kafka topics? They definitely have to be different topics for my use case (while they must always have the same schema), but I don't know if I would violate some hidden semantic relationship between schema name and topic name. Would this "only" break conventions or lead to actual problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the Confluent Schema Registry, then each topic is a unique subject, but the schemas can indeed be shared since matching schemas would generate matching ids.

This isn't a problem and saves storage on the brokers by not storing duplicate information

Comment: "then each topic is a unique subject" confuses me, so I do need to have a unique subject identifier? So to be precise, if I have subject `ABC-key` and `ABC-value` in my (Confluent) Schema Registry, and I left the config to be the default `TopicNameStrategy`: will there be no collisions with having topic `ABC` and topic `ABCD`, which are both filled with records that refer to the same schema (called `ABC` in the SR, as there exists no `ABCD` schema)?

Comment: As an example, if you set the key and value to the same schema, subject ABC-key and ABC-value will be created, but you'll only find schema ID 1 in the registry API. There's no way to get a schema by name, it requires both subject and version